# Propagate `requires` in lambda functions in Dafny

Tags: dafny

How do I prove something about the assumption of a lambda function? I would like to prove the following

```
lemma propagate_requires(f: int --> int,y:int)
ensures ((x: int) requires f.requires(x) => f(x)).requires(y) == f.requires(y)
```

This should be obviously true from my understanding. However, Dafny does not propagate the assumption.

How are these `requires` actually handled by Dafny?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is verifiable in one direction but not in opposite direction.
This verifies

```
lemma propagate_requires(f: int --> int,y:int)
  ensures ((x: int) requires f.requires(x) => f(x)).requires(y) <== f.requires(y)
{}
```

This does n't verify

```
lemma propagate_requires(f: int --> int,y:int)
  ensures ((x: int) requires f.requires(x) => f(x)).requires(y) ==> f.requires(y)
{}
```

There is issue related to this https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues/2137.